# Angular moment datepicker: get the current date format

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, momentjs

We are developing an internationalized web app and therefor use `@angular/material-moment-adapter` to localize our dates. This works great, however we also want to display to our users how to they have to enter the Date.

[image]

[image]

So how can I get the value for a the **en** format (MM/DD/YYYY) but also the **de** format (DD.MM.YYYY).

I looked into the `DateAdapter` but didn't find an option

Comment: Are you looking for a way to get `MM/DD/YYYY` given `en` and `DD.MM.YYYY` given `de`? Take a look at momentjs' [`localeData()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/).

Comment: Yes I do. I have to use moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L') but how do I tell it to use "de", "en" ....

Comment: Ex: moment.locale('DA');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`localeData`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/) and `longDateFormat` to get locale specific format.

> You can access the properties of the currently loaded locale through the `moment.localeData(key)` function. It returns the current locale or a locale with the given key.

```js
function getFormatForLocale(localeCode){
  return moment.localeData(localeCode).longDateFormat('L');
}

['en', 'de', 'fr', 'it'].forEach(code => {
  console.log(`code ${code}: ${getFormatForLocale(code)}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```